# Google drive error occured in google colab pro subscription

Tags: google-colaboratory

Subscribed to **Google Colab pro** and getting the Google drive error occured .I have selected the TPU with higher ram for execution of deep learning algorithms.

Please let me know how to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: While training the model, notification comes in the lower left corner mentioning "google drive error" in google colab. Detailed error is not given.